# Windows Phone 7 Pop-up window

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

Ive used an app which uses a type of popup window.
When you click on some specific, a 'popup' scrolls up from the bottom of the screen and fills the whole window. If i remember correctly its semi transparent. It has several text sections and a range of buttons on it. What sort of control is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid the Popup class. At the recent PDC they said it wasn't hardware accelerated or something. I'd place a Canvas or Grid or combo of both at the bottom of the page (so its on top, but you can also set Z order) and translate it off the screen. Then animate it on. Look at Collapsing the control when not used if you're having problems with it altering layout or using resources.

Myself, as I've a few years under my belt, I'd write a new control and use the parts and states model to transition it on and off etc. but if you're new to Silverlight then this is maybe a head-jar.

If you expect to be learning Silverlight fully, check out Karen Corby's MIX08 session on control authoring. In fact, check out all the sessions at http://videos.visitmix.com/

http://videos.visitmix.com/MIX08/T20

Luke

Comment: +1 I'd also consider (on device) performance carefully before using popups for any type of animation. Luke is correct that popup contents will not go to the render thread.

Comment: What would be the real world problems of the popups that the end user might actually experience.

Comment: @Dan, just general slugglishness in its transitions or any animations thereon - this could slow background operations since it'll be using the CPU and not the GPU, I'm sure its not a terrible sin to use a simple pop of text.

Answer (score 8):

The coding4fun Windows Phone Toolkit includes an example of doing a popup window (for an about box) that works correctly. I've found it very useful.

http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/

Comment: yes, it works perfectly, but when use aboutPrompt1.Hide() function, then on 2nd attempt it doesn't hide, which is a bug. Chk it... the childwindow of silverlight is working perfectly but on WP7.

Answer (score 1):

It was probably the [popup class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for the actual popup window with other supporting controls (buttons, textblock, etc) being used.